# How to test server side rendered web applications?

Tags: web, responsive, server-side-rendering, web-testing

I know some basic that Server-side rendering is the process of rendering the web page files from server and passing them to the browser (client-side)

There is one website that has recently been implemented in server-side rendering, now speed for that website seems pretty fast but what are the testing points I should consider while testing the newly implemented SSR page/website?